# Is UICollectionView suitable for dynamic data (Swift code)?

Tags: swift, view, ios8, uicollectionview

I'm looking to develop an app with a layout similar to a web dashboard. As it's being used as a monitoring app, the user needs to enter data into individual cells at regular intervals. In order to streamline the code and allow reuse, a grid-based layout using UICollectionView seems to be the most appropriate solution but I need to display dynamic data, specifically elapsed time and a countdown timer. This would need a cell or supplementary view to be updated every second and I am concerned that the continued reload calls will result in a significant performance hit.

What would be the best solution? A vanilla UICollectionView doesn't look like it would be practical so I thought I could create a custom View Controller which contains two subviews - one containing the timer and the other encapsulating the UICollectionView. Does anyone have any recommendations or other suggestions?